# AJV - How to validate relative references

Tags: jsonschema, ajv

I have a json that is used as ref in another json in the same folder:

`jsonBase.json`

```json
{
  "type": "number",
  "title": "Your salary",
  "presentation": {
    "inputType": "money"
  }
}
```

`jsonFinal.json`

```json
{
  "$ref": "jsonBase.json",
  "presentation": {
    "currency": "EUR"
  }
}
```

When using AJV validate, the schema is invalid (it's missing the required properties), ignoring the `base.json`.

I checked this [github issue](https://github.com/ajv-validator/ajv/issues/113) and [read the docs](https://ajv.js.org/guide/combining-schemas.html) but I still don't understand exactly what change I need to make in order for the json to be valid.

Here's the [codesandbox with demo](https://codesandbox.io/s/ajv-validate-relative-refs-3boslw?file=/src/index.js).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only use `$ref` in a schema to reference a schema. It doesn't work in JSON instances.